# DLM package, issues about specifying models with time-varying coefficient

Tags: time-series, state-space-models, time-varying-covariate, dlm

I've been working on DLM package for the past few weeks. I've read the package manual and the paper written by Petris "dlm: an R package for Bayesian analysis of Dynamic Linear Models", but I am still not sure about how to setup a dlm object for my model, stated as follows:

[image]

I've got data for St, At, Wt and Xt, and I am interested in estimate three state variables (which are considered as time-varying) **alpha_t**, **beta_t** and **gamma_t** as well as one time-invariant coefficient **c**. Forget about the c*Xt part for now, and to simplify the problem, I consider **alpha_t**, **beta_t** and **gamma_t** as random walk. Then my R code for the model setup is:
[image]

I have four variables to be estimated, which are the variances for the observation error and state error. My first question: Is this the right specification for my model ? (ad, WOMvolume,interaction are just the data)

If so when I call fit <- dlmMLE(sale,parm=rep(0,4),build=buildFun), it returned error "Error in storage.mode(mod[[i]]) <- "double" " why is that?

I also tried another way to setup the model, like
[image]

This time, when I called `fit <- dlmMLE(sale,parm=rep(0,4),build=buildFun)`, it return the error "`Error in dlmLL(y = y, mod = mod, debug = debug) :` 
 `error code 2 from Lapack routine dgesdd`" why is that?

I am really not sure about how to setup my model using DLM. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks for your help in advance :)

---

(response to F. Tusell)

After some tryouts, I think I figured out how to setup my model using dlm(). Here is the code.

[image]

But when I called dlmMLE function like fit <- dlmMLE(sale,parm=rep(1,4),build=buildFun), I got an error stating "**error code 2 from Lapack routine dgesdd**". And I googled for the error, and it turns out that error code 1 from Lapack routine dgessdd should be a convergence problem. Is there any way get around the issue? Or does that mean my model does not have a solution? I am using R 3.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Any help would be most welcome!

---

(2nd edit in response to  F.Tusell)

I am working on some equation combining both time-variant and time-invariant coefficients. Say I have this,

[image]

y, X1 and X2 are observed time-series data. Two coefficients are of interest here, one is time varying and the other is constant. Based on your previous replies, I setup my dlm like this,

[image]

And I can get the state vector by "model3Filter$m". But it does not seem right since the second state variable I get is changing instead of constant. Anything wrong with my construction? Maybe FF or GG ?

Appreciate so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt defines an entirely different model than the first. In your first attempt you are creating an object in which V and W are *not* matrices, as they should be. Better use the constructor function `dlm` that will take care of those details for you, rather than using `list`.

Comment: @Tusell, thanks for your comments, and I tried to use dlm(), which is dlm(m0=rep(0,4), C0=100000*diag(3), JFF=matrix(1:3,1,3), GG=diag(3), X=cbind(ad,WOMvolume, interaction), V=x[1], W=diag(c(x[2],x[3],x[4]))). But I got an error saying that FF is missing, but in my case FF is time-varying, I should use JFF instead, why is that?

Comment: @Tusell, BYW, I think V should be a scalar rather than a matrix. Is that like V is designed to be a matrix? then I should set V = matrix(x[1])?

Comment: After some tryouts, I think I figured out how to setup my model using dlm(). (see my question for details)

Comment: You can pass it to dlm() as an scalar, dlm will take care.

Comment: One thing you could try is to parameterize in terms of squares (or exponentials). For instance, instead of V=x[1] above, V=exp(x[1]). You should realize that under dlm there is a call to a routine that maximizes the likelihood, but it is completely unaware of what sort of function that is. It migth well choose values of x[1] negative, which do not make sense as variances, and abort the process. Similarly for W, you must ensure it always remains non-negative definite.

Comment: @ Tusell, thanks so much. I finally got the results :) Now I am wondering what if I incorporate c*X_t? I have both time-varying coefficient and constant coefficient to be estimated, how shall I specify dlm object?

Comment: I read some of your previous replies on similar problems and you suggested that the variance could be set to 0. So, I will have a 0 on the diagonal in the matrix W, is that right? Shall I also put a parameter in m0 to be estimated? But m0 seems only to accept numeric values.

Comment: Yes, but in that case you should not have  W=diag(x[1],x[2],x[3]), but rather something like W=diag(exp(x[1]),exp(x[2],0). No, m0 leave it as it is.

Comment: I understand about about W, but I don't understand where do I get the estimated constant coefficient, which is c in my model? Does dlmMLE also output estimated c or ?

Comment: The constant coefficient is the element of the state vector whose variance has been set to zero in W.

Comment: yes, that is right. But I have to estimate the constant coefficient (I don't know it in advance), right? how shall I do that ?

Comment: When you run the Kalman filter, the last value of the corresponding element of the state vector is the value you want.

Comment: @Tusell, I am wondering whether the time-varying coefficients, alpha_t, beta_t, and gamma_t have a trend. I have assumed that they follow a random walk, but how shall I test whether they have a upward trend or downward trend? I know it's out of the scope of DLM package. I would be appreciate it very much if you could help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: If you just wanted to check the existence of a trend, you might fit a local linear trend and inspect the level and slope element of the state vector. But a monotonic trend would require a non-linear constraint. I wouldn't know how to handle it.

Comment: @Tusell, okay, I see. Another question. Since I have assumed that alpha_t, beta_t and gamma_t follow a random walk, they should be a **non-stationary** time series right? But when  I apply ADF(AR(1)) to test whether it is true, the results seems to indicate that, roughly speaking, they are stationary. I am confused about it.

Comment: @Tusell, what do you mean by non-linear constraint?

Comment: Non-linear consttraint: something which cannot be stated as Ax=c, with A being a matriz and x, c vectors. For instance x_1 > 0 would be a non-linear constraint.

Comment: Regarding your previous question, yes, a random walk is non.stationary. I do not know what ADF does, from the name an augmented Dickey-Fuller test? Two series can be non-stationary and a linear combination of them stationary (hence, cointegrated). Perhaps ADF is testing that?

Comment: @Tusell, I am so sorry for my late reply. Yes, ADF is for augmented Dickey Fuller test. I've already figured it out. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @Tusell, hi, I still have some problems dealing with estimating time-varying coefficient and constant coefficient at the same time. Would you please check my problem presented below, thanks so much :)

Comment: Please don't use answer spaces to clarify your question or hold discussions with other commenters or answerers. If it ends with "any help would be most welcome" it's not an answer, but a continuation of the question. If you want to convert this to an answer, edit it (e.g. remove the parts that aren't answer), and flag to ask to have it restored. If you do that, you'd also need to edit your question (since I moved much of this to your question) to remove the parts there that *are* answer.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient is meant to be constant; but remember the Kalman filter performs estimation at every point in time,so the estimates of the coefficient will vary over time. This should cause no surprise: if you perform ordinary linear regression with constant coefficients with, say, the first half of the sample and then with the whole sample, your estimates of the constant coefficients will also be diferent.  Similar thing happens here.

Comment: I am working on some equation combining both time-variant and time-invariant coefficients. See the second update to my question.

Comment: oh, I see. But then what should be used as estimate of beta (in a constant sense) if I only wanna one value to represent the coefficient?

Comment: You probably want the last value, which makes use of the whole sample.